# How to find items with at least one identical parameters in R?

Tags: r, match

I know how to find items with the same parameters, but when there are many parameters and I want to find items with at least one identical parameters, I don't know if there is any functions that I can use.
for example I have a table that each item has 2 parameters:

```
Mydata<-data.frame(item=1:4,P1=c(7,12,11,8),P2=c(12,3,11,7))
Mydata
#   item  P1  P2
# 1    1   7  12
# 2    2  12   3
# 3    3  11  11
# 4    4   8   7
```

In the example, item1 and item2 both have parameter 12, so they are similar. I expect to get a table that shows the item and its similar items maybe like this:

```
#  item  x1  x2
#    1   2   4
#    2   1  NA
#    3  NA  NA
#    4   1  NA
```

Is there any function that can do this?

Comment: There is no 12 for item 1 and item 2.

Comment: `set.seed()` would have helped...

Comment: Yes, because you didn't set a seed.

Comment: can you edit your output? it's very messy ...what is the 4 on the first row third column??

Comment: There can me only one item with similar items or what you want to see if there are more than one similar item?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel the first row means item1 is similar with item2(both have 12) and item4(both have 7).

Comment: @Batanichek  I want to find all similar items with at least one identical parameters.

Comment: How you result should be if Mydata<-data.frame(item=1:4,P1=c(7,12,11,8),P2=c(12,3,11,12))?

Comment: @Batanichek then in the output, x1=c(2,1,NA,1), x2=c(4,4,NA,2).

Comment: This sounds like it might be more of a machine learning application.

Comment: @Batanichek Thank you but it shows "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'" when I run it. I am new to R and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: My bad its not work if you have 1 item which similar with more than 1 item.

Comment: @MikeWise totally not, check out the solution below.

Comment: Yes, a re-read of it shows he wants to "find items with at least one identical parameters". I think the title and the question need an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do base `R` with a single loop with `sapply`:

```
Mydata <- data.frame(item=1:4,P1=c(7,12,11,8),P2=c(12,3,11,12))

#  item P1 P2
#1    1  7 12
#2    2 12  3
#3    3 11 11
#4    4  8 12

m = Mydata[-1]

res = sapply(1:nrow(m), function(i){

    mat = matrix(is.element(unlist(m), m[i,]), ncol=ncol(m))
    x   = Filter(function(x) x!=i, which(!!rowSums(mat)))

    if(length(x)==0) 
        return(rep(NA,ncol(m)))

    c(Mydata[,1][x], rep(NA, ncol(m)-length(x)))
})

cbind(Mydata[1], t(res))
#  item  1  2
#1    1  2  4
#2    2  1  4
#3    3 NA NA
#4    4  1  2
```

Comment: @Yigreen, here is a more generalist solution which can handle any number of parameters.

Comment: ok I see, there is a small nasty recycling typo. It's corrected.

Comment: thanks! worked perfectly. though I thought there would be some function that makes it simpler...

Comment: the problem is not so obvious! so it needs elaboration and there may be a function in a dark package but I doubt.